# Sort by problems with Matomo

Tags: sorting, report, matomo

I’m working on a Custom Report in Matomo, an I’m experiencing some problems with the sorting of the columns.

The setup is as following:

**Report type:**
 - Table

**Dimensions:** 
 - Server Time - Week of Year (End of visit)

**Metrics:**
 - Visits
 - Total Number of Internal Searches

No filter is used.

My problem is that the report is sorted by “Visits" as default. 
Can this somehow be changed to “Server Time - Week of Year” instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on title "Server Time - Week of Year (End of visit)", the data should be sorted based on that.